# find the frequency of occurences of any given word in a sentence using java

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the occurrence of given word in a sentence using java.

My input contains two lines, first line contains one word and second line contains the sentence.

```
Sample Input:
love
There is only one happiness in this life,to love and be loved.

Sample Output:
1
```

I tried below below program to print the value 1 - but its printing for each word rather for same word. Can someone please help me to fix this?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        String test = "love\n" + "There is only one happiness in this life,to love and be loved.";

        System.out.println(test);

        Map<String, Integer> wordCount = Arrays.stream(test.split("\\s+"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> 1, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2));

        // Print word frequencies
        wordCount.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s %d\n", k, v));

    }

}
```

Comment: Well you don't even try to look up the word `love`, you just parse it into the sentence you're scanning.

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions in Java and using [groupCount](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount())

Comment: Are you trying to _count_ occurrences, or just to check for the presence of a word?

Comment: Not answering your question, but note that there's a simpler way to get the map you want: `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting())`

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed with a simple if statement. All you have to do is make sure the current key matches the first line. In order to do this, get the first line by itself before mapping the string.

---

```
String test = "love\n" + "There is only one happiness in this life,to love and be loved.";
// Get first line "love"
String word = test.split("\\n")[0];
/*
 * Get second line (the line to be mapped)
 * "There is only one happiness in this life,to love and be loved."
 */
String senctence = test.split("\\n")[1];
System.out.println(test);

Map<String, Integer> wordCount = Arrays.stream(senctence.split("[\\s+]"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> 1, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2));

// Print word frequencies
wordCount.forEach((k, v) -> {
    // Check if the key matches the primary input
    if (k.equals(word))
        System.out.printf("%s %d\n", k, v);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first problem was to input key value into count. Try separately:

```
String key = "love";
String test = "There is only one happiness in this life,to love and be loved.";
```

Then

```
    // Print word frequencies
    wordCount.forEach((k, v) -> {
        if(k.equalsIgnoreCase(key))
        System.out.printf("%s %d\n", k, v);
    });
```